# window.external is null for new windows

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

Problem; window.external is null for child windows

I have a WinForms application that contains a CEFSharp Chromium browser control on the main form. The complete code is provided here; note this is not my application but a much simpler example that shows the problem.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private WebInteropAPI _objForScripting;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += OnFormLoaded;
        _objForScripting = new WebInteropAPI();
    }

    private void OnFormLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetupBrowser();
        _browser.Load("http://localhost:80");
    }

    private void SetupBrowser()
    {
        _browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.ResolveObject += ResolveObject;
        _browser.FrameLoadStart += FrameLoadStart;
    }

    private void FrameLoadStart(object sender, FrameLoadStartEventArgs e)
    {
        _browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("CefSharp.DeleteBoundObject(\"external\"); CefSharp.RemoveObjectFromCache(\"external\"); CefSharp.BindObjectAsync(\"external\");");
    }

    private void ResolveObject(object sender, JavascriptBindingEventArgs e)
    {
        var repo = e.ObjectRepository;
        if (e.ObjectName == "external" && repo != null && _objForScripting != null)
        {
            BindingOptions options = BindingOptions.DefaultBinder;
            options.CamelCaseJavascriptNames = false;
            try
            {
                repo.Register("external", _objForScripting, true, options);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the WebInteropAPI class for completeness

```
    public class WebInteropAPI
    {
        public string Push(string name, string payload)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("#### Push() name:" + name + " payload:" + payload + " ####");
            return payload;
        }

        public void PushData(string payload)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("#### PushData() payload:" + payload + " ####");
        }
}
```

On form load I register my interop and navigate the browser to a local HTML page on my machine;  it looks as follows

```
    <html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Invoke Push Data on Host</button>
        <a href="http://localhost:80" class="open-popup">Launch child iFrame</a>
    </p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.open-popup').click(function(e) {
                                          e.preventDefault();
                                          window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'width=1000,height=750');
                                          });
    </script>
    <script>
function myFunction() {
  window.external.Push("This is the name property","This is the payload data property");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Running the application results in the rather fetching UI

[image: Windows Form hosting CEFSharp showing a localhost page]

Clicking the button does indeed invoke the method on my WebInteropAPI
[image: Output from clicking the button]

However; clicking the link to open a new child window and then clicking the button results in an error
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE;  I've found something that works but I'm unsure if it's good or bad from a standards point of view.

My updated Forms view now looks like;

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private FrameHelper _frameHelper;
    private JSObjectHelper _jsObjectHelper;
   
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += OnFormLoaded;
    }

    private void OnFormLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetupBrowser();
        _browser.Load("http://localhost:80");
    }

    private void SetupBrowser()
    {
        _jsObjectHelper = new JSObjectHelper(new WebInteropAPI());
        _frameHelper = new FrameHelper();

        _browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.ResolveObject += (s, a) =>
        {
            _jsObjectHelper.ResolveObject(a);
        };

        _browser.FrameLoadStart += (s, a) =>
        {
            _frameHelper.FrameLoadStart(_browser);
        };

        _browser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler(_frameHelper, _jsObjectHelper);
    }
}
```

The magic now happens in the LifeSpanHandler

```
    public class LifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
{
    private readonly FrameHelper _frameHelper;
    private readonly JSObjectHelper _jsObjectHelper;
    private ChromiumWebBrowser _browser;
    public LifeSpanHandler(FrameHelper frameHelper, JSObjectHelper jsObjectHelper)
    {
        _frameHelper = frameHelper;
        _jsObjectHelper = jsObjectHelper;
    }

    public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser){}

    public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser){}

    public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(string.Empty);
        _browser.Bounds = ((ChromiumWebBrowser)chromiumWebBrowser).Bounds;
        _browser.BrowserSettings = ((ChromiumWebBrowser)chromiumWebBrowser).BrowserSettings;
        _browser.FrameLoadStart += (s, a) => { _frameHelper.FrameLoadStart(_browser); };
        _browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.ResolveObject += (s, a) => { _jsObjectHelper.ResolveObject(a); };
        newBrowser = _browser;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And for completeness; here's the frame helper and the JsObjectHelper

```
    public class FrameHelper
{
    public void FrameLoadStart(IWebBrowser browser)
    {
        browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("CefSharp.DeleteBoundObject(\"external\"); CefSharp.RemoveObjectFromCache(\"external\"); CefSharp.BindObjectAsync(\"external\");");
    }
}

    public class JSObjectHelper
{
    private readonly WebInteropAPI _objForScripting;
    public JSObjectHelper(WebInteropAPI objForScripting)
    {
        _objForScripting = objForScripting;
    }

    public WebInteropAPI ObjForScripting { get; }

    public void ResolveObject(JavascriptBindingEventArgs e)
    {
        var repo = e.ObjectRepository;
        if (e.ObjectName == "external" && repo != null && _objForScripting != null)
        {
            BindingOptions options = BindingOptions.DefaultBinder;
            options.CamelCaseJavascriptNames = false;
            try
            {
                repo.Register("external", _objForScripting, true, options);
            }
            catch
            {
             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From memory FrameLoadStart is only called for the main browser.  Try moving your BindObjectAsync call into JavaScript.

Comment: Sadly the page content is beyond my control; I've updated the example with something that does work but I'm unsure if I'm going about it the wrong way.

Comment: For testing purposes, modify the example you provided and confirm that it works. You can implement http://cefsharp.github.io/api/86.0.x/html/T_CefSharp_ILoadHandler.htm and assign an instance to http://cefsharp.github.io/api/86.0.x/html/P_CefSharp_IWebBrowser_LoadHandler.htm